# Google Chrome position: fixed

Tags: html, google-chrome, position

On my site http://stevengeorgeharris.com I have a fixed header, which scrolls down with the user. It works perfect in Firefox, Safari, ie, ipad, iphone but not CHROME. As I scroll down the header (#nav) disappears/jumps around then reappears further down. It seems to be when it scrolls over #info.

Can anyone help me debug it, tried for ages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the z-index on your video.

Comment: Perfect!! It's always the little things that catch me out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your link in chrome and this is what I got while scrolling:

[link](http://prntscr.com/uedey)

Answer (score -1):

Try removing top and left, and use margin-top instead. This should work.